# Almacenar valor de una variable en un objeto

Tags: javascript, html

Tengo un calendario interactivo, y para añadir notas nuevas al hacer clic encima del día extraigo el formato fecha de dicho día y lo almaceno en una variable, todo bien hasta ahí, el problema es que para que se muestre en el Calendario como una "Nota activa" debo añadirlo a un objeto predefinido llamado "events".

Un ejemplo es el siguiente:

```
events = { "2017-06-30": {"number": 5, } }; 
$('.responsive-calendar').responsiveCalendar('edit', events);
```

En el calendario, el recuadro del día 30 de Junio del 2017 ya tiene un nuevo evento, con 5 tareas dadas por el "number". Como se ve en la [imagen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zcTgm.png)

Ahora con este codigo lo programo con lo dicho al principio, nada pasa, coloque alertas con los valores del objeto "events":

```
$(".responsive-calendar").responsiveCalendar({
            onDayClick: function(events) {
                var keyy = $(this).data('year')+'-'+addLeadingZero($(this).data('month'))+'-'+addLeadingZero($(this).data('day'));
                events = { keyy : {"number": 5}};
            for (var keey in events) {
            if (events.hasOwnProperty(keey)) {
            alert(keey); // variable
            alert(events[keey]); // opcionales
        }
$('.responsive-calendar').responsiveCalendar('edit', events);
```

**Al hacer la comprobación, me aparece que el objeto está tomando el nombre de la variable "keey" mas no su valor.**

[image: IMAGEN]

¿Como resuelvo esto?

Comment: Se parece que estas usando var keyy en unos lugares y keey en otros.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ya que tu objeto **JSON** se compone de un valor en una variable debes armar tu objeto primero como **String** y luego pasarlo a **JSON** con el método [JSON.parse()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/JSON/parse).

Ejemplo:

```
$(".responsive-calendar").responsiveCalendar({
 onDayClick: function(events) {
  var day = $(this).data('year')+'-'+addLeadingZero($(this).data('month'))+'-'+addLeadingZero($(this).data('day'));
  events = JSON.parse('{"'+ day +'": {"number": 5}}');
  for (var i in events) {
   if (events.hasOwnProperty(i)) {
    alert(i); // variable
    alert(events[i]); // opcionales
   }
  }
 }
});
$('.responsive-calendar').responsiveCalendar('edit', events);
```

A titulo informativo y solo para complementar puedes también usar el método [eval()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/eval).

Ejemplo:

```
  events = eval('{"'+ day +'": {"number": 5}}');
```

Sin embargo, antes de usar `eval()` es importante tengas en cuenta lo siguiente:
[JSON.parse() vs eval()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1843343/json-parse-vs-eval)

Espero esto te ayude!! ;))...

Comment: ¡Gracias! Funciona a la perfección, eres lo mejor.